# How to resolve "conflicting types error" in C?

Tags: c

For the following C code (for swapping two numbers) I am getting the "conflicting types" error for `swap` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("enter the numbers to be swapped");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    printf("before swap");
    printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,b);
    swap(&a,&b,sizeof(int));
    printf("after swap");
    printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,b);
    getch();   
}
void swap(void *p1,void *p2,int size)
{
     char buffer[size];
     memcpy(buffer,p1,size);
     memcpy(p1,p2,size);
     memcpy(p2,buffer,size);
     return(0);
}
```

Compiler diagnostics:

```
<source>:10:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'swap' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  swap(&a,&b,sizeof(int));

  ^~~~
program:15:6: warning: conflicting types for 'swap'
 void swap(void *p1,void *p2,int size)
     ^~~~
```

Can anybody tell why that error is coming?

What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that `swap` was not declared before it is used. Thus it is assigned a "default signature", one which will in this case not match its actual signature. Quote [Andrey T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187690/andreyt):

> The arguments are passed through a set
>   of strictly defined conversions. `int *`
>   pointers will be passed as `int *`
>   pointers, for example. In other words,
>   the parameter types are temporarily
>   "deduced" from argument types. Only
>   the return type is assumed to be `int`.

Aside from that, your code produces a bunch of other warnings. If using `gcc`, compile with `-Wall -pedantic` (or even with `-Wextra`), and be sure to fix each warning before continuing to program additional functionality. Also, you may want to tell the compiler whether you are writing ANSI C (`-ansi`) or C99 (`-std=c99`).

Some remarks:

- Put spaces after commas.
- Make `main` return an `int`.

  - And make it `return 0` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS`.
- Import the definition of `getch`: `#include <curses.h>`.

  - Or just use [`getchar`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar).
- Import the definition of `memcpy`: `#include <string.h>`.
- Don't return something in a `void` function.
- You may want to use `malloc` to allocate a buffer of variable size. That will also work with older compilers:

  ```
  void swap(void *p1, void *p2, int size) {
      void *buffer = malloc(size);
      memcpy(buffer, p1, size);
      memcpy(p1, p2, size);
      memcpy(p2, buffer, size);
      free(buffer);
  }
  ```

Comment: @AndreyT: thanks for that note. Clearly my view of what happened didn't match reality. I incorporated your remark in the answer.

Comment: Don't use 'getch()' from `<curses.h>` unless you are also prepared to initialize the library (or put up with core dumps when you don't).

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare swap before using it. For example, put `swap` above main, or add a prototype for `swap` like this:

```
void swap(void *,void *,int);
int main ()
```

Incidentally `main` should be `int` not `void` and usually it returns the value zero, unless there is an error.

Answer (score 3):

First off, the actual error message wouldn't hurt.

Secondly, making buffer of [size] only works on some compilers (that's a new feature, not all compilers have it yet). Are you sure yours does?

Thirdly, you need to declare swap before calling it. Add a prototype at the top of the file:

```
void swap(void *p1,void *p2,int size);
```

Answer (score 2):

You failed to declare your `swap` explicitly, forcing the compiler to make assumptions about the function at the point of the call. The compiler, in accordance with C rules, will assume that `swap` is

```
int swap(int *, int *, size_t)
```

Later you declare your swap as

```
void swap(void *, void *, int)
```

which is obviously different from what the compiler assumed. This is the conflict the compiler is telling you about.

Also, your `void swap` attempts to `return 0`. What were you trying to achieve by that?

P.S. It's `int main`, not `void main`.

P.P.S. The program is not guaranteed to produce any output if its output does not end in a new-line character.

Answer (score 1):

You may wonder why the program compiles at all without a prototype for swap(), and that's because the compiler is more than a C99 tool. It also compiles C89 and K&R C programs.

C89 added the prototypes. Prior to C89, the compiler didn't need to see the declaration (the prototype) of a function unless it returned something other than `int` and the types of the formal parameters were not known to the compiler at all. The compiler just called every function with the types of the actual arguments, which received a set of default argument promotions to simplify things. The programmer would run the `lint` utility to cross-check actual and formal parameters. This program is still shipped with the BSD distributions.

K&R programs and their corresponding code styles are still accepted by your compiler, so when it sees a function for which no prototype is available it just goes ahead and calls it anyway.

In this case, you switch paradigms in between the call and the definition of the function. The K&R C assumptions the compiler made about the undeclared function when it had to generate a call turned out not to be valid. Even if you had written the whole program in the K&R style the compiler would have made the same complaints when it found out the *real* types of the function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

With GCC, this is a warning,
when you dont declare a function before using it, the compiler tries to guess the declaration using the type of call made to that function.Hence the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it compiles on http://codepad.org (after removing the `getch()`, which is irrelevant). Maybe your compiler complains about using memcpy on non-restricted pointers?

In `swap()` `p1` and `p2` are not guaranteed not to be aliases. This is an actual bug waiting to happen - calling swap on `&a[i]` and `&a[j]` might  blow up `memcpy` when `i==j`. Either use `memmove` (which is guaranteed not to blow up on overlapped areas) or declare the pointers `restricted`.

Comment: The missing declaration of `swap` compiles because formally it is not an error in C. It is UB. But how you managed to compile `return 0` in a `void` function is not clear to me.

Comment: @AnT to argue with your opinion from 10 years ago, formally it is an error in C... ;)