# Conflicting types error message

Tags: c, types

My little program in ANSII C gives me a "Conflicting Types" error message when I compile it. And I don't know why that is, especially given the fact that I've tested the same situation in a different .c file with no problems whatsoever.

The code is as follows:

```
    void search(char *v, Message *l){

    long int max;

    max=countNodes(l);
```

(... This part doesn't matter, I assure you that...)

```
    } //end of the "search" function

    long int countNodes(Message *l){

    long int i=0;

    while(l!=NULL){

    i++;
    l=(l->nseg);

    }

    return(i);
    }
```

So, the "countNodes" function determines the number of nodes in "l" (linked list). Then, that number is returned to the "search" function. But the compiler keeps giving me a "Conflicting Types" error message, and I don't know why... I think that everything is fine and well written.

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a [mcve], please read up on it and *edit your question*. Also note that you're supposed to include the *exact* error message you are getting.

Comment: Where is the prototype for `countNodes()` declared before it is called?  You must be coding to antique (C90) rather than modern (C11, or C99) standards if you don't have the prototype before the use or definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conflicting types error in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779358/conflicting-types-error-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler basically reads your file line by line. So when it reads `max=countNodes(l);`, it doesn't "know" your `countNodes` function yet.

You have two options:

- put your `countNodes` function before your search function.
- put the prototype of your `countNode` function before the `search` function (read about "prototypes in c" if your not familiar with it).